# passport-google-token Invalid Credentials

Tags: android, ios, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to make Google oAuth authentication with passport-google-token in order to authenticate a Android Client and iOS app.

We have two credentials generated in console.developers.google.com. One created using client oAuth id-> android the other under the client oAuth id->web.

The mobile apps are using the first one, and the other one is using in a backend with nodejs and express. The android client is able to retrieve a access token from google and it is send to the backend the token. The passport-google-token is receving the access token correctly. But when the are trying to get the profile receive a 401 - Invalid credentials.

```
passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

In the client id and client secret I am using the keys from the web client credentials. But my code never go under the callback function.

My questions is. Do the credentials have to be related in any way so that I can use the access token? I mean the mobile credentials and the the credential i am using in the backend.

I was following this flow https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

EDIT: I've realize that the problems is also happening in the iOS app.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I've changed passport-google-token by [passpport-google-id-token](https://github.com/jmreyes/passport-google-id-token) instead of the passport-google-token.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but if someone's is getting into this error today with `passport-google-oauth20` that's because by default the underlying OAuth2 strategy will fetch the Google's user profile as part of the authentication.

To solve that, you have two choices:

- If you don't require the profile to be loaded, pass the option `skipUserProfile: true` when you instantiate the strategy
- If you need the profile, add `profile` as a scope, e.g. `scope: ['profile']`